# How can I add a hyperlink to a N/ui/nmessage in suitescript?

Tags: javascript, scripting, customization, netsuite, suitescript

I have a message banner pop up on certain records and I'd like to incorporate a link in the code.

For example, the message states: "Message........ Click Here"

I'd like for the 'Click Here' to be a link to a saved search. Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thank you!

I am not too familiar with suitescript and javascript so I am unsure how to incorporate a link into the actual message of a N/ui/message

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the HTML text for an [anchor tag](https://www.w3schools.in/html/anchor) to the message. For example

```
  context.form.addPageInitMessage({
        type: message.Type.INFORMATION,
        duration: 0,
        message: "You've reviewed this requisition.<a href='/app/common/search/searchresults.nl?searchid=1730'>Search it</a>",
        title: "Information"
    });
```

...produces...

[image: screenshot]

which opens the search with id 1730. There's nothing to stop you changing the URL to a transaction, entity, suitelet etc.